# How does Maven work?

Tags: java, maven

I need to send my Maven project(written in IDEA) to another guy. So I've got a question : which files exactly i should send. As i understand there are: 
.idea folder , src folder and pom file. Afther this i just need to perform this command in directory with pom file on another computer:

> mvn install

And i've got built project and jar file.Am i right?

If it is correct i've got a problem - i've got nothing in my local maven repository.

```
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Pa
ragonCase ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1251 actually) to copy filtered resources,
i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Paragon
Case ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ ParagonCase ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\Kru\IdeaProjects\PopularWords\target\
surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running MainTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.118 sec

Results :

Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ ParagonCase ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ ParagonCase ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\Kru\IdeaProjects\PopularWords\target\ParagonCase-1.2.
jar to C:\Users\Kru\.m2\repository\ru\nick\kru\ParagonCase\1.2\ParagonCase-1.2.j
ar
[WARNING] Failed to create parent directories for tracking file C:\Users\Kru\.m2
\repository\ru\nick\kru\ParagonCase\1.2\_remote.repositories
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\Kru\IdeaProjects\PopularWords\pom.xml to C:\Users\Kru
\.m2\repository\ru\nick\kru\ParagonCase\1.2\ParagonCase-1.2.pom
[WARNING] Failed to create parent directories for tracking file C:\Users\Kru\.m2
\repository\ru\nick\kru\ParagonCase\1.2\_remote.repositories
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.874 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-03-31T20:25:37+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/155M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Read a good book about Maven... This is way too broad for Stack Overflow. I suggest https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/

Answer (score 0):

> I need to send my Maven project(written in IDEA) to another guy. So I've got a question : which files exactly i should send.

The only things you need to send are `pom.xml` and the folder`src`. And you don't have to send the `.idea` folder because it is IDEA specific and nothing to do with Maven; so the receiver can choose his own favorite IDE.

> And i've got built project and jar file.Am i right?

Yes, you're right.

> If it is correct i've got a problem - i've got nothing in my local maven repository.

The project seems to have built correctly as you can see from the following log output:

> [INFO] Installing C:\Users\Kru\IdeaProjects\PopularWords\target\ParagonCase-1.2.jar to C:\Users\Kru.m2\repository\ru\nick\kru\ParagonCase\1.2\ParagonCase-1.2.jar

To verify this you can go to the `target`directory and see if the **jar** file is there.

Why you're not getting the artifacts in the local repository may have to do with the warning displayed where Maven is complaining that it cannot create parent directories:

> [WARNING] Failed to create parent directories for tracking file C:\Users\Kru.m2\repository\ru\nick\kru\ParagonCase\1.2_remote.repositories
>   [INFO] Installing C:\Users\Kru\IdeaProjects\PopularWords\pom.xml to C:\Users\Kru.m2\repository\ru\nick\kru\ParagonCase\1.2\ParagonCase-1.2.pom
>   [WARNING] Failed to create parent directories for tracking file C:\Users\Kru.m2\repository\ru\nick\kru\ParagonCase\1.2_remote.repositories

So I would suggest that you investigate why Maven cannot create thos directories.

Answer (score -1):

You should have something in your local .m2, but there's no need for you to send that to your partner.  Maven will go out to the central repo if it doesn't find a JAR in the .m2.

If you're saying you have JARs that are private to your app that aren't available in any central Maven repo then you do have a problem.  Anyone using your app will have to satisfy the dependencies when they build.

If you cannot put your app into GitHub and have others successfully build it by checking out, then you're doing it wrong.